# How to setup DynamoDB to serve data to a website?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

Brand spanking new to AWS. Serving a static website(S3), no problem of course. I'd like to stay in the AWS family for the backend entirely but I'm feeling really silly for not being able to figure out how to fetch data from DynamoDB.

What is the system, or other AWS components, that need to be setup to make simple queries to DynamoDB?

Comment: On what platform are you building your website?

Comment: Bootstrap/js. I'm not sure what you mean by platform exactly. It's deployed on S3.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-dynamodb-tutorial.html

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow below developer guide from AWS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-dynamodb-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Checkout AWS Lambda and AWS API Gateway; It will allow you to query dynamodb, do something with the data, and then return the results you need in a HTTP endpoint.

The following is the AWS tutorial on creating a simple microservice using both : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example-configure-event-source_1.html